# Matlab Regression Tree Predict

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, regression, decision-tree

I am using Matlab Regression Tree toolbox and I would like to use predict function as described [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/compactregressiontree.predict.html)

I have constructed my tree like this:

```
tree = fitrtree(data,labels,'CrossVal','on');
```

I can see the tree has been constructed. I can even visualize it. However when I try to use predict, the predict function gives this error:

```
Error using predict (line 126)
No valid system or dataset was specified.
```

When I type `which predict`, this came up: `/home/sami/Desktop/MATLAB/R2016b/toolbox/ident/ident/predict.m`

How can I use the predict function of regression tree?

Regards

Comment: That `predict` seems to be a part of System Identification toolbox, `which -all predict` would tell you all the `predict` visible to MATLAB.  If you are able to fit a regression tree but not predict from the tree there could be something wrong with your installation.

Comment: with which -all predict i can see the statistical toolbax's predict i.e . So how can I use that specific predict? Thanks

Comment: How did you call `predict`?

Comment: y = predict(tree,data);

Comment: "Using the 'Crossval', 'KFold', 'Holdout', 'Leaveout', or 'CVPartition' options results in a tree of class RegressionPartitionedModel. You cannot use a partitioned tree for prediction, so this kind of tree does not have a predict method.

Otherwise, tree is of class RegressionTree, and you can use the predict method to make predictions." https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/fitrtree.html#bt6cr84-3